# How to change the color of heading ?

Tags: android

I want change the color of @+id/txtcommentheading but it show the error @+id/welcomelayout is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout please suggest for the same or otherwise it show show forceclose error.

Here is my code,

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            tools:context=".HomePageActivity"
            android:background="@drawable/img"
            >

            <!-- android:background="@drawable/img" -->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/banner" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Login"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/header"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/welcomelayout"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
                            android:layout_width="160dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:hint="Username"
                            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >
                            <requestFocus />
                        </EditText>
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
                            android:layout_width="160dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:hint="Password"
                            android:inputType="textPassword" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtForgetPassword"
                            android:layout_width="160dp"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:autoLink="web"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/forgetpassword"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                            android:layout_width="160dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:text="Login" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/Line2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Login"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#ffffff" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/body"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Line2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/merchantlayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtcommentheading"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="Merchant Comment heading"
                            android:textColor="@color/green"
                            android:textSize="19dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/txtcomment"
                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                             android:text="Merchant Comment"
                             android:textColor="@color/green"
                             android:textSize="15dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                    <View
                            android:id="@+id/Line3"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="2dip"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/merchantlayout"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="#ffffff" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/welcomelayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/Line3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtwelcome"
                            android:layout_width="200dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="left"
                            android:text="Medium Text"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@color/green" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
                            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:text="Logout" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutbtn"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/welcomelayout"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnProducts"
                            android:layout_width="310dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:text="Menu"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutbtn"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnCallus"
                            android:layout_width="155dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:text="Call Us to Order"/>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
                            android:layout_width="155dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:text="Register" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/user_Profile"
                            android:layout_width="155dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:text="My Profile"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout6"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/btnfacebook"
                            android:layout_width="145dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/facebook"
                            android:background="#537531" />

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="8dp"
                            android:layout_height="10dp"
                            android:visibility="invisible" />

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/btntwitter"
                            android:layout_width="145dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/twitter" 
                            android:background="#537531"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/body"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/versionNo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:text="Version 1.0"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Amith suggested your `welcomelayout` is in LinearLayout which is causing you the problems. But I want to add an additional note that **Nested Layouts are not considered good for Android Programming** .

Nested Layouts uses a lot of memory and computational time since the complete Layout becomes complicated. Once single **RelativeLayout** will work for you and will be a lot clean.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem then please check this answer and mark the question solved. Happy Coding !!!

Comment: please thumbs up for my question

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with setting text color. You are not allowed to use  `android:layout_below="@+id/welcomelayout"` inside Relative layout because the `welcomelayout` is present in Linear layout only, If you want to use `android:layout_below="@+id/welcomelayout"` you have to change your Relative lay out to Linear  and give the orientation

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            tools:context=".HomePageActivity"
            /* Specify orientation here */
            android:background="@drawable/img"
            >

            <!-- android:background="@drawable/img" -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/banner" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Login"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/header"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    /* Specify orientation here */ >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/welcomelayout"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
                            android:layout_width="160dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:hint="Username"
                            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >
                            <requestFocus />
                        </EditText>
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
                            android:layout_width="160dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:hint="Password"
                            android:inputType="textPassword" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtForgetPassword"
                            android:layout_width="160dp"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:autoLink="web"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/forgetpassword"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                            android:layout_width="160dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:text="Login" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/Line2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Login"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#ffffff" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/body"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Line2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    /* Specify orientation here */ >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/merchantlayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtcommentheading"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="Merchant Comment heading"
                            android:textColor="@color/green"
                            android:textSize="19dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/txtcomment"
                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                             android:text="Merchant Comment"
                             android:textColor="@color/green"
                             android:textSize="15dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                    <View
                            android:id="@+id/Line3"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="2dip"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/merchantlayout"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="#ffffff" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/welcomelayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/Line3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtwelcome"
                            android:layout_width="200dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="left"
                            android:text="Medium Text"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@color/green" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
                            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:text="Logout" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutbtn"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/welcomelayout"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnProducts"
                            android:layout_width="310dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:text="Menu"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutbtn"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnCallus"
                            android:layout_width="155dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:text="Call Us to Order"/>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
                            android:layout_width="155dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:text="Register" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/user_Profile"
                            android:layout_width="155dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:text="My Profile"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout6"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/btnfacebook"
                            android:layout_width="145dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/facebook"
                            android:background="#537531" />

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="8dp"
                            android:layout_height="10dp"
                            android:visibility="invisible" />

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/btntwitter"
                            android:layout_width="145dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/twitter" 
                            android:background="#537531"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/body"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/versionNo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:text="Version 1.0"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```